# Problema ao ordenar um array com sort()

Tags: javascript, array, classificação

Um deles ocorre quando desejo ordenar um *array* de números.

Ex:

```
var a = [44,7,5,6,4,2,1];
a.sort();
console.log(a);
```

O resultado esperado seria:

[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 44], mas o que sempre me é retornado é [1, 2, 4, 44, 5, 6, 7].

Este é um *array* bem pequeno, mas no que eu estou trabalhando(com mais de 300 ocorrências) tem acontecido o mesmo. 115 aparece antes de 2, por exemplo.

Comment: Existem vários sites onde pode encontrar tutoriais e exemplos práticos de Javascript. Para o caso das ordenações pode ver aqui: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para ordenar números precisas de passar uma função de comparação ao método.

Teste com:

```
function(a, b) {
   return a - b;
}
```

O retorno dessa função é o que indica ao método a posição do elemento em relação ao que está a ser comparado.

Ou seja:

```js
var a = [44, 7, 5, 6, 4, 2, 1];
a = a.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
console.log(a);
```

Como o [@Maniero indicou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118476/129) a comparação que o método faz (sem lhe passar uma função) não faz o que pensas. [A especificação oficial é](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11):

> If comparefn is not undefined and is not a consistent comparison function for the elements of this array (see below), the behaviour of sort is implementation-defined.

Ou seja, quando não é passada uma função o que é feito fica à vontade do *browser*. Na MDN refere-se que os valores serão tratados como *String*  e acho que é isso que a maior pare dos *browsers* faz. ([ler mais na MDN em Inglês aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort))

Answer (score 6):

O JavaScript trata os elementos como `string`, por isso acontece o "problema". Solução:

```js
var a = [44, 7, 5, 6, 4, 2, 1];
a.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
console.log(a);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/SortCriteria.js).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma para ordenar corretamente, passando uma função de `callback` como parâmetro para a função `sort`:

```js
var a = [44,7,5,6,4,2,1];
a.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
document.write(a);
//console.log(a);
```

Ou também poderia fazer dessa forma:

```js
var a = [44,7,5,6,4,2,1];
a.sort(function(a, b){
  return a > b;
});
document.write(a);
```